# Expected Unqualified ID before token

Tags: c++, compilation, token

learning the ropes with C++ here and we're exploring `cmath` library so bear with me.

Currently, I need to create a program that calculates the Surface **S** of a triangle using the Herron's formula. So far, I'm reaching [this](https://pastebin.com/ydSX1LpB)

But when I try to compile it in G++, I get the classic "Expected unqualified-id before '' token" and it points towards one of the { brackets.

Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and read the help on how to ask.

Comment: Elaborating, had you actually created an MCVE, it would look like this: `int main(); {}`. If you couldn't tell what's wrong with that, it would be straightforward to look for a simple C++ program and find the error. In fact, creating an MCVE will lead you to discover the problem most of the time, and if not, it's much easier for someone else to use than whatever code you had originally.

Comment: Do apologize for that, I'll keep it in mind in the future! :)

Answer (score 1):

`int main();` should be `int main()` (you're defining it, not just declaring it). Also, you're missing definitions for `S` and `p`.

Comment: Weird, I did try it without ; but it made no difference. I guess I messed up somewhere else as well, but it's working now, thank you!

Comment: @fail0verfl0w Never forget that a program can contain more than one error at a time and that these errors can feed off and build upon one another. Sometimes you will strike down one syntax error only to find the ten that it hid from the compiler. Do not panic and undo. If the fix you made makes sense, carry on.